# Convert column tuple into a string

Tags: python, pandas, string, tuples

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
    ip  date    destination_bytes   source_bytes
                 count  max mean    min sum count   max mean    min sum
0   10.0.0.1    2020-11-13 13:57:00 3   3   2.0 1   6   3   5   2.666667    1   8
1   10.0.0.1    2020-11-13 13:59:00 0   0   0.0 0   0   0   0   0.000000    0   0
2   10.0.0.1    2020-11-13 14:01:00 1   2   2.0 2   2   1   1   1.000000    1   1
```

Which results in column names as tuples, i.e `('ip',''),('date',''),('destination_bytes','sum')`.

How can I convert these into joined strings, i.e `ip,date,destination_bytes_sum`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) with `strip`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join).str.strip('_')
```

Or in list comprehension with `f-string`s:

```
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}'.strip('_') for a, b in df.columns]
```

Alternative with `if-else`:

```
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' if b != '' else a for a, b in df.columns]
```

Comment: quite straight forward. It does join them also on empyt second item `ip_ date_` though.